Problems adding a background image to a Div in React
I'm having trouble adding a background image to a div. In regular JavaScript, it works and allows me to define an object with a specific size and color. However, the same approach isn't working in React. I've tried different methods, including adding the color in both the CSS file and the JSX file, but nothing seems to work.
I've tried the following methods, but they only work when I add text between the  elements. I need them to work without text. Why is this happening?
import DiskImg from "../img/favicon.png";

<div 
      className="muplayer-songcover" 
      style={{ 
        backgroundImage: `url(${DiskImg})`, 
        backgroundSize: 'cover', 
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
      }}
    >
    </div>

.muplayer-songcover {
  background-image: url(../img/favicon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
}


Do you have any error on compilation ? if no, check with console if the style are defined, it should work

I've tried it, and there are no compilation errors

In the first big of code the div has no dimensions so won’t show up. In the second piece of code the CSS looks OK, but how are you creating the div?

It is because you are using a div tag, no matter what you do, give div a colour or whatever, unless it contains some content, it won't show up. Try some other tag, like with  tag.

import css file from jsx file
import "./file.css"

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
